# What PSU Should I Get For A Mini-ITX Board

Tags: power-supply

I have a [BIOSTAR NM70I-1037U motherbord](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813138393) that I am using to bring an old PC back to life.

Power requirements should be minimal, although I don't know how to determine what the actual requirements would be.

The existing power supply I have for the case doesn't have the right connectors for the new motherboard.

The case has approx. 55mmx85mmx900mm space for a PSU.

[image]

Since I am just refurbishing an old PC I don't want to spend too much so old models that I might be able to pick up from ebay or elsewhere can be acceptable answers.

I am quite happy to mod the case to make it fit - up to a point. e.g. cutting a hole for a cable is OK but having a giant PSU sticking out the side is probably not!

Since I have replaced the motherboard with the mini-itx one above there is huge amounts of airflow. It is just going to be sitting on my desk for playing old Sega arcade games on an emulator.

Comment: You have a major problem - this PSU is custom made. It isn't conforming to many (any?) of the typical ATX, EATX, SFX, TFX etc. specs that exist for modular PSUs. Also, it is plain that this computer is some kind of industrial unit. Will it be experiencing high temperature variation, vibration, humidity, restricted airflow, excessive dust, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing environmental concerns, I'd suggest the following, so long as you don't need to power too many peripherals (it doesn't have the connectors for it): 
**[picoPSU-150-XT + 102W Adapter Power Kit](http://www.mini-box.com/picoPSU-150-XT-102-power-kit)**. You should be able to cram the whole thing into that space, leaving just the power cord coming out. The big problem here is that pretty much any solution will not mate perfectly to whatever hole is in the other half the case which would normally have gone over where the original PSU's plug is. This is problematic for any industrial PC for a variety of reasons, but perhaps you can jerry rig a seal? Without knowing the environment of operation, it's impossible to say whether an off-the shelf DC adapter such as the one featured here would be sufficient, but you chose an off the shelf motherboard/CPU solution to your problem so I'm operating on the assumption that this might be OK.

The big advantages here are that it is efficient, doesn't require active cooling, and has no moving parts.